# PowerBI is auto summing values with same date

Tags: charts, powerbi, controls

I´m triying to build a simple control chart, a simple graph used to study how a process changes over time. Data are plotted in time order (dd/mm/yyyy).

The problem is, when there is more than one data per date, PowerBI is adding it up. I already tried turning Summarization off in the Data view, and changing the format of the values and the data.

[The graph showing a value of 18,894.79 for the 12/11/2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVgjw.png)

[How the data actual looks, 3 different values for the same date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbeQe.png)

I know this looks pretty simple, but I can't find a way to solve it.

EDIT: Getting individual data now. The problem is, I´m getting dot plot instead of line chart.

[new image (3), after following Murray´s suggestion.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2pTD.png)

Comment: Grouping/Aggregating is the normal behavior. Question is, what actually you wants from them?

Comment: What makes each value different? Are you missing a time field? There are only dates and values so you have no option but an aggregate or average. If you had another column (say color), then you could plot that as the legend to get independant values for each date.

Comment: Thanks Murray, that definitely helped. Now is showing values individually. The problem now is, the line chart is showing dots only. Please see the third image on the OP.